# Xslt Check if next text after tag is a given char

Tags: xml, xslt

Having this:

```html
<a><b>Hi</b><c/><d/>Friend</a>
```

For this specific example, how can I reference the first char after tag "b", in this case the letter "F"?.

Comment: I think we need a better definition of "after".

Comment: @zx485 Please do not edit OP's code - you don't know what it looks like. Indenting code is not always benign. In this example, you have created a bunch of whitespace text nodes, as well as added a newline character to the existing text node.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: OK, I noticed the difference. It made your answer inapplicable. I'll refrain from that.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific example, the instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(/a/b/following-sibling::text()[1], 1, 1)"/>
```

will return "F". Whether that will work for other cases is not clear.